# How to implement auto save functionality in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-5.0, autosave

I want to implement auto save functionality.

I have a silverlight application, in which, we are sending data on server on clicking of a button. Now i don't want to click on that button, i want, my data should be post to server periodically with time interval of 20 or 30 seconds.

Plz provide me your valuable suggestion to how to implement this

Comment: Just do whatever you do in that button click handler in a DispatcherTimer's Tick method. Be sure to disable the timer while a send is in progress.

Comment: Can you plz share any link or data that can help me for implementing it

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to keep a session alive. It does the same thing that you are trying to do; automatically calls a service after specified regular intervals:

```
        public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set up timer
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt =
            new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        // Set to call every 5 minutes
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0, 0);
        // Set up event handler
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        // Start timer
        dt.Start();
    }
    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Call web service
        Ping();
    }

    void Ping()
    {
        WebTest.otsref.SilverlightServiceClient webService = new WebTest.SilverlightServiceClient();
        webService.PingAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i have implemented it. I have one more doubt, i am writing these all code in MainViewModel. And i also want to save data in the situation of browser crash. Then how to save my data in browser crash condition also

Comment: You can't. It runs in the browser, so if that crashes, your app will stop working too. You would either need to save data to the server every time it is changed [which might not be that much more of an overhead than saving every 30 seconds], or to save changes on the client in between saves using IsolatedStorage.